# Converting strings to integer in c#

Tags: c#

I just asked a question about how to convert a number to a string with leading zeros. I had some great answers. Thanks so much. I didn't really know which to mark correct as they were all good. Sorry for the people I didn't mark correct.

Now I have strings like

```
001
002
003
```

How do I convert back to integers? something like the opposite of Key = i.ToString("D2");

Mandy

Comment: Quick question - are you assuming base-10? Because I have seen leading-0 numbers to be other bases, like octal.

Answer (score 7):

Quite easy that also.

```
string myString = "003";
int myInt = int.Parse( myString );
```

If you aren't sure if the string is a valid int, you can do it like this:

```
string myString = "003";
int myInt;
if( int.TryParse( myString, out myInt )
{
  //myString is a valid int and put into myInt
}else{
  //myString could not be converted to a valid int, and in this case myInt is 0 (default value for int)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = int.Parse(string)
```

or

```
int number;
int.TryParse(string, out number)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string strNum= "003";
int myInt;
if( int.TryParse( myString, out myInt )
{
  //here you can print myInt
}else{
  //show error message if strNum is invalid integer string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is it:

```
int i;

if ( Int32.TryParse("003", i) )
{
    // Now you have the number successfully assigned to i
}
else
{
    // Handle the case when the string couldn't be converted to an int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the String to an Int

```
Int32.Parse("001");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
int.TryParse(stringValue, out i)
```